# Android camera API

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to make a camera application on android, the application capture photos, but after taken photos ; if i pressed back button it **shows a black screen ,and if i tried to open another application  the camera is locked !!**
in the **logcat** when the application starts >> the camera opens 3 times !

I want this application to capture images then take the captured image and convert it to Mat for processing ; when i press back button it should finish and the camera release .
**any hints or ideas ??** 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to manage the camera, surface, callbacks etc, or do you just want the output (ie the picture the user takes) ?

If all you care about is the picture, the pass off an intent to get the picture, and listen for the return.